# SQL to return if value is double

Tags: sql

I have a question on how to validate if a row's doubled when other columns meet criteria.
The table looks looks like this:

```
Type   Name    ID    Am
O      Name1   1234  1
O      Name1   1235  1
O      Name1   4569  2
X      Name2   1234  1
X      Name2   4569  2
C      name3   1234  1
```

For type O, I have under Name1, 2 ID's for the same Am = 1.
I'd like to to do a query that would check if multiples IDs can be found under same type & name & am values and return if >1, but ignore the rest of the types.

Thank you!

Comment: What DBMS are you using?

Comment: With that sample table data, what is the expected result?

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
select type, name, am
from table
group by type, name, am
having count(*)>1
```

Answer (score 0):

most dbms support row_number,so you can use this

```
select * from
(
select *, row_number() over(partition by Type,Name,Am order by ID) as rn
from t
) t1 where t1.rn>1
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to check if a combination of type/name has more than one am value?

If so:

```
select type, name
from t
group by type, name
having min(am) <> max(am);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use `NOT EXISTS` :

```
SELECT t.*
FROM table t
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 
              FROM table t1 
              WHERE t1.Type = t.Type AND t1.Name = t.Name AND t1.Am = t.Am AND t1.ID <> t.ID
             );
```